# Extract Text After Charecter and String

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Kind of lost on what to do here. I have a a cell in A2 that is in the format shown below. I need to extract all text after Query Summery - and to end at the ============ beffore Query. All it should pull through is New event testing in area 15. I have mutiple entries like this in the A column but in the same format. Not a clue on how I would extract this. Would VBA be the best choice?

```
============
Main Data - Information on this is the main data
============
Query Summery - New event testing in area 15
============
Query - New mine created for testing in minecraft and brought forwards 15 times today
============
```

Comment: Try `instr()` and `mid()`

Comment: Never ever done anything like this beffore so these functions are new to me.

Comment: Excellent. Sounds like you have an opportunity to learn something new!

Comment: so type in google, MSDN Instr and MSDN Mid  and you will get a full detailed explanation for each

Comment: Yes VBA would be the best choice. See this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05e63829(v=VS.90).aspx
, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx @Sorceri ahead of me i see ;)

Comment: Thanks Chaps. I will get on this now ^_^. Will report back what I have done

Comment: Why would a formula not be good in this circumstance?

Comment: Hint: use the position returned by the first [InStr function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to start the search with the second.

Comment: @neosegauk Theoretically a formula would work, but it would probably be a bit more complex. You'd use the `Find` formula to find the instance of `Query Summery -` then use three more nested `Find` formulas to find the third instance of the delimiter "====".

Comment: @pnuts touché! I assumed that the entries could be in any order, not necessarily *always* in the order submitted, so I accounted for that. If not, your approach makes more sense.

Comment: @pnuts That's definitely a reasonable assumption. I'm just a perpetual pessimist! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a custom function in VBA, if you're willing to go that route. The code below creates a User Defined Function with three parameters: input string, the delimiter (or separator), and the option to return.

Assuming the string is in Cell `A1`, the formula would look like this:

`=CustomSplit(A1,"============", "Query Summery -")`

The code behind, to be inserted into a standard module, looks as follows:

```
Function CustomSplit(sInput As String, sDelimiter As String, sFind As String)
    Dim sArray() As String

    sArray() = Split(sInput, sDelimiter)

    For i = LBound(sArray) To UBound(sArray)
        If sArray(i) Like "*" & sFind & "*" Then
            CustomSplit = Application.Trim(Replace(Replace(sArray(i), sFind, ""), Chr(10), ""))
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    CustomSplit = CVErr(xlErrNull)
End Function
```

Comment: Does this trim out `vbCrLF` and `vbLF` extraneous (and likely undesired) characters?

Comment: @Jeeped I specifically trimmed out `vbLF` using `Chr(10)` in the nested replace function. I suppose I could've trimmed all of them, but I was waiting to see if that sufficed.